# average num js and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanna show the average number in array, so I use

```
    var sum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<$scope.students.length; i++){
        sum += +$scope.students[i].gpa;
        return sum
```

in scope, with arr

```
[
        {name : 'Vasya Pupkin', gpa : '4.8'},
        {name : 'Petia Vasechkin', gpa : '3.2'}
    ];
```

but it shows - 4.8.

[example](https://plnkr.co/edit/bZyCtFeWxn4IAkD4iFSo?p=preview) , what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a brace, so you return the sum's value at the first iteration:

```
var sum = 0;
for(i=0; i<$scope.students.length; i++){
    sum += +$scope.students[i].gpa;
} // HERE
return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning sum inside loop. Thus loop is executed once and first value is returned.

```
var sum = 0;
for(i=0; i<$scope.students.length; i++){
    sum += +$scope.students[i].gpa;
}
//Return after loop
return sum;
```